# Apache load balancing - how to control which server is accessed?

Tags: java, apache, application-server

if I'm building a apache server with load balancing to different backend servers: can I have control to which server a request is handed? Eg for a specific user always use a specific server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same back and server for specific session. (Please check apache documentation for sticky session approach)
Regarding different users to different servers similar topic i discussed there: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverTS/thread/67e05eec-1f26-47e1-ade5-e4c904d5f70c

Answer (score 0):

> Eg for a specific user always use a specific server?

I don't know why you would want to do that, but I think you need to read about session stickiness.